# How to reduce title to one line in MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I am creating documents using VBA in Word with data being pulled from Excel. Unfortunately the titles are sometimes so long that they get wrapped in Word.

I need the titles to remain on one line. I plan on doing this by simply changing the font size until the text fits on one line.

Searching for solutions to this problem I have come accross `.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines)`.

Unfortunately when I run this code, it keeps on telling me that there are 0 lines to my text. **How can I get the code to give the correct number of lines?**

Here is my code so far (only the relevant section):

```
'Set document title
Dim sLength As Integer
Dim rStatTitle As Range
Set rStatTitle = wkb.Worksheets("Daten2").Range("nfStatTitle") 'Fund Title

With tblTitle.cell(2, 1)
    .Range.Text = rStatTitle.Cells(1, 1)
    Do Until .Range.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) <= 1
        sLength = Len(rStatTitle.Cells(1, 1))
        .Range.Font.Size = .Range.Font.Size - 1
    Loop
End With
```

FYI: `tblTitle` is a word table and is declared as such further up in the code.

Comment: @EmmadKareem i'm not sure I understand what you mean by "where the message is coming from"? The I can post the full declaration of tblTitle if you like... a fixed font won't do in this case. The title should be font size 44 unless it doesn't fit, in which case it is allowed to be smaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7c8daf5-a640-4766-8070-b54ded1fa88f/counts-lines-in-a-table-cell?forum=worddev) says you should shrink your `Range` so it excludes the end-of-cell marker.

```
Dim newRange As Range
With tblTitle.cell(2, 1)
    .Range.Text = rStatTitle.Cells(1, 1)
    Set newRange = .Range
    newRange.End = newRange.End -1
    Do Until newRange.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) <= 1
```

Comment: Your answer worked... at least as a first step! Now I get the result of 1 when it should be 2. Any idea why that could happen? Thanks for your help already!

Comment: Sorry... my bad. It provides the correct answer! Thanks a lot!